# Query slower with index on 14M rows table

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

DB: Amazon RDS MySQL (OS: Linux, 2 vCPU, Memory: 8GB)

I have a table with almost 14M rows of data.

```
CREATE TABLE `meterreadings` (
 `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `meterid` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 `metervalue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
 KEY `meterid` (`meterid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see, I use an index on meterid.

Another table which stores device IDs (around 100 rows of data)

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
`Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`meterid` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`location` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `meterid_UNIQUE` (`meterid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

To get 15 minute aggregated data, I use the below query

```
SELECT AVG(metervalue) as value
 , DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%d %b %Y %H:%i") as label 
FROM meterreadings 
WHERE meterid IN (SELECT meterid from devices) 
  AND date_time BETWEEN '2018-07-23' AND '2018-07-24' 
GROUP BY DATE(date_time), HOUR(date_time), MINUTE(date_time) DIV 15 
ORDER BY date_time ASC;
```

Query performance is very bad - It takes approximately around 12 seconds to execute, and causes a temporary spike in DB server usage as well.

EXPLAIN on this query returned this:

```
1   SIMPLE  devices index   meterid_UNIQUE  meterid_UNIQUE  19      125  
   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  meterreadings   ref meterid meterid 19  devices.meterid 322  
   Using where
```

I dropped the index on meterreadings and surprisingly the query performance is better - almost about 6 seconds now. I am still wondering why?

EXPLAIN on the query after dropping the index

```
1   SIMPLE  meterreadings   ALL                 14580167    Using where; 
Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  devices ref meterid_UNIQUE  meterid_UNIQUE  19   
   meterreadings.meterid    1   Using index
```

I am currently doing my query operation on the table without index - Is there a way I can optimize the table / query to do the operation faster (like a composite index on two columns?)

[The table is growing approximately by around 40 rows per second]

Comment: Try to add a composite index `(date_time, meterid)`. Or ever covering index `(date_time, meterid, metervalue)`.

Comment: This will never be fast because you group by a function, thus impossible to build an index. However there are virtual columns in 5.7 which you can use in secondary indexes. I would explore in that direction.

Comment: @Akina - Since that covering index is only slightly smaller than the table, it is probably not worth doing.

Comment: @akuzminsky - Since the query probably needs to scan the entire table, indexes are probably useless -- the Optimizer will choose to scan the data and not use any index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should play with it a bit, because it might not be clear beforehand what solution will produce the best results.

A few points to consider

1. It is very likely that an index on the date column will provide you with better selectivity, as it has a higher selectivity.
2. Composite indexes are usually a good idea, but please make sure to chose the order correctly `date_time, meterid`  vs. `meterid, date_time`. In most cases it makes more sense to leave columns with dense values (i.e dates, floats) to the end, as any column in the index following them is unlikely to have any effect. ( try `meterid, date_time` for an index.)
3. Subselects might force the optimizer to use a specific plan. Try converting it into a join if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why have `WHERE meterid IN (SELECT meterid from devices)`?  Aren't all the devices represented in both tables?

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `meterid_UNIQUE` (`meterid`)
```

Get rid of `id` and change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(meterid)
```

To be clean you should use 15-minute intervals everywhere, not

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%d %b %Y %H:%i") as label
```

Instead consider

```
FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / (15*60))
```

Which can be converted back via

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(... * (15*60))
```

And formatted.  For example:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), DATE_FORMAT( 
       FROM_UNIXTIME( 
          FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) / (15*60))
                      *(15*60)
                           ), "%d %b %Y %H:%i") as label;
+---------------------+-------------------+
| NOW()               | label             |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| 2018-08-21 13:43:42 | 21 Aug 2018 13:30 |
+---------------------+-------------------+

SELECT AVG(metervalue) as value,
       DATE_FORMAT( 
       FROM_UNIXTIME( 
          FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / (15*60))
                      *(15*60)
                           ), "%d %b %Y %H:%i") as label 
       FROM meterreadings 
       WHERE date_time >= '2018-07-23'
         AND date_time  < '2018-07-23' + INTERVAL 1 DAY  -- bug fix
       GROUP BY meterid,   -- Don't you want this, too?
                label
       ORDER BY meterid,
                label;
```

I fixed the case where you were including two midnights in one day.

More more efficiency, change

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `meterid` (`meterid`)
```

to this *if your query is the main one*

```
PRIMARY KEY (date_time, Id),  -- to make it a range scan
INDEX(id)   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

If you can be sure that there are never two readings for a meter in the same second, get rid of `id` and have

```
PRIMARY KEY(date_time, meterid)
```

(Again, this may not be optimal, depending on what other queries you have.)

All of that will help some.  If you want another 10x speedup, build and maintain [*Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Answer (score 0):

As @akuzminsky indicated a generated column can help. The obvious way of doing this with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) DIV 15*60` however `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is one of the functions not allowed in a generated column. So despite the ugliness of expression below, it does result in interval15 being the rounded timestamp to 15 minutes.

```
ALTER TABLE meterreadings ADD interval15 timestamp AS (
  SUBTIME(date_time, 
         CONCAT("0:", MINUTE(date_time) MOD 15, ":", SECOND(date_time),".", MICROSECOND(date_time)))),
  ADD INDEX interval15 (interval15);
```

The new query is:

```
SELECT AVG(metervalue) as value
 , DATE_FORMAT(interval15, "%d %b %Y %H:%i") as label 
FROM meterreadings
WHERE interval15 >= '2018-07-23'
      AND interval15  < '2018-07-23' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY interval15
ORDER BY interval15 ASC;
```

If you where optimizing this query only you could append the metervalue to the interval15 index and then the result would be from the index alone.

Comment: using `TO_SECONDS` in the generated expression might have been possible. Didn't test it.